# JS Thumb scroller

Tags: javascript, image, scroll

I have a thumb scroller on my site and the problem is, when thumbs reach end scroller leaves blank spaces before it goes back to beginning...  Can anyone help how to achive this... Thank you in advance!

This is the url: http://marinmartinovic.com/MK_test/

It could take a little bit to load. Still need to optimize images...

This is js:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {






/*
 *
 * SORTING INDEX NUMBERS
 *
 */

function sortIndexNumbers(){

    loadPhotoIndex = 0;
    indexNumbers = [];

    for(var i = 0; i<photosLength;i++){
        indexNumbers.push(i);
    }

    if(photoIndex === 0){
        indexNumbersToAdd = indexNumbers.splice(photosLength-1, 1);
        indexNumbers = indexNumbersToAdd.concat(indexNumbers);
    }
    if(photoIndex > 1){
        indexNumbersToAdd = indexNumbers.splice(0, photoIndex -1);
        indexNumbers = indexNumbers.concat(indexNumbersToAdd);
    }

    loadPhoto();
}




/*
 *
 * LOAD THUMBS
 *
 */

var aThumbsWidth = [];

var speedThumb = 750;

var thumbIndex = 0;
var thumbSwiped = 0;
var thumbsWidth = 0;

function loadThumb(){

    $('<img src="'+ aThumbs[thumbIndex] +'">').one('load', function() {

        $(".thumb-content ul").append('<li><div class="thumb" id="thumb" data-index=' + thumbIndex + '><img src="'+ aThumbs[thumbIndex] +'"></div></li>');

        //setTimeout(function() {

            aThumbsWidth.push($('.thumb-content .thumb img').get(thumbIndex).width);    
            thumbsWidth+= $('.thumb-content .thumb img').get(thumbIndex).width + thumbSpacing;

            thumbIndex++;

            if(thumbIndex < aThumbs.length){
                loadThumb();
            }

            // all 3 loaded

            if(thumbIndex === aThumbs.length){

                highlightThumb();
                // find thumb and get its position
                console.log(photoIndex);
                var thumbPosition = $('.thumb-content').find("[data-index='" + photoIndex + "']").position().left;
                selectThumb(thumbPosition);
            }

        //}, 50);

    }).each(function() {
        //if(this.complete) $(this).load();
    });

}


/*
 *
 * SWIPE THUMB SLIDER
 *
 */

var currentThumb = 0;
var currentThumbShift = 0;

$(".thumb-content").swipe( {
    tap:function(event, target) {
        if(!loadingInProgress){
            photoIndex = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-index'));
            selectPhoto();
            highlightThumb();
        }
    },

    triggerOnTouchEnd: false,
    swipeStatus: swipeThumbStatus,
    allowPageScroll: "vertical",
    threshold: 200
});

function swipeThumbStatus(event, phase, direction, distance, fingers)
{
    thumbSwiped = distance;

    /*if( phase === "move" && (direction === "left" || direction === "right") )
    {
        var duration = 0;

        if (direction === "left"){
            scrollThumbs(currentThumbShift + distance, duration);
        }

        else if (direction === "right"){
            scrollThumbs(currentThumbShift - distance, duration);
        }

    }

    else if ( phase === "cancel")
    {
        scrollThumbs(currentThumbShift, duration);
    }*/

     if ( phase === "end" ){
        if (direction === "right"){
            if(!loadingInProgress){
                prevPhoto();
                setThreePhotos(prevPhoto, 1500, 1);
            }
        }
        else if (direction === "left"){
            if(!loadingInProgress){
                nextPhoto();
                setThreePhotos(nextPhoto, 1500, 1);
            }
        }
    }

}

function selectThumb(distance){
    currentThumb = currentThumb + photoIndex;
    TweenLite.to($(".thumb-content"), 0.75, {left: -distance, ease:Power4.easeOut, force3D:true});
}

$('body').on('click', '.thumb', function(e) {
    if(!loadingInProgress){
        photoIndex = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-index'));
        selectPhoto();
        highlightThumb();
        selectThumb($(this).position().left);
    }
});

function highlightThumb(){
    $('.thumb').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.thumb-content').find("[data-index='" + photoIndex + "']").css('opacity', '0.5');
}


/*
 *
 * NEXT PREVIOUS THUMB
 *
 */

var arrow = false;

var nextThree ;
var intervalBuffer;

$('#next-thumb').click(function(event) {
    if(!loadingInProgress){

        photoIndex += 2;
        if((photoIndex+1) >= aPhotos.length){
            photoIndex = 0;
        }
        selectPhoto();
        highlightThumb();

        // find thumb and get its position
        var thumbPosition = $('.thumb-content').find("[data-index='" + photoIndex + "']").position().left;
        selectThumb(thumbPosition);

    }
});

$('#prev-thumb').click(function(event) {
    if(!loadingInProgress){
        photoIndex -= 2;
        if((photoIndex+1) < 0){
            photoIndex = aPhotos.length-1;
        }
        selectPhoto();
        highlightThumb();

        // find thumb and get its position
        var thumbPosition = $('.thumb-content').find("[data-index='" + photoIndex + "']").position().left;
        selectThumb(thumbPosition);
    }
});

function setThreePhotos(callback, delay, repetitions) {

    clearInterval(threePhotos);
    var x = 0;
    var threePhotos = setInterval(function () {

       callback();

       if (++x === repetitions) {
           clearInterval(threePhotos);
       }
    }, delay);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code! Is it really necessary to reproduce your problem? Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I deleted what is not necessary... thx